# intent on shema regarding idolatry

Tags: avodah-zarah, shema

in the [shema](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/706162/jewish/Translation.htm) we recite "Take care lest your heart be lured away, and you turn astray and worship alien gods and bow down to them"

what intent should one have while reading this given that the inclination for idolatry was [abolished](http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5771/vaeschanan.html)

Comment: [The article you linked](http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5771/vaeschanan.html) seems to answer your question: while we might not literally bow before an idol, many people often let their *yetzer hara* lead them into anger, promiscuity, etc.

Comment: @Mike its just drashas

Comment: Why assume that you need to have any sort of special intent?

Comment: I don't even get the question. For whatever reason, billions of people still for one reason or another worship avoda zara. Even many Jews, for example, are Christian. Clearly the issue of avoda zara is still relevant, so the question about kavana doesn't start.